# Node oracle connection pool issue

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection-pooling

I am using node js and connecting to oracle db. Oracle db has a limitation of 100 sessions for this user and I use connection pool of 100 in node js. When the number of db hits increases, I get a timeout error. The db call is made in async way in a try catch loop, with a close in the final clause. Any answers please, thanks

Invoking node APIs from a mobile app, when the user counts increase, either oracle refuses connection or getting a timeout error